# Samsung's S-Plasma Ion - scientific basis

Tags: ions, hydrogen

Has anyone come across a scientific study of the S-Plasma Ions that Samsung claims will purify air from microbes, allergens and free radicals? I would prefer publicly available research findings.

The following is a quote from http://www.samsungspi.com:

> The Samsung SPi generates Hydrogen atom ($\ce{H+}$) and Oxygen ion ($\ce{O_2-}$) which reacts together to form Hydroperoxyl radicals which the positively charged biological contaminants then reacts with three hydrogen elements of its protein structure before forming water vapor. Also, the Hydrogen atom ($\ce{H}$) will combine with $\ce{OH}$-radical to form a water vapor and neutralize harmful $\ce{OH}$-radical.

It also matches the description found on the product itself. See http://winniekepala.com/2011/03/ionizer-review-samsung-virus-doctor/ .

Here's a quote from the video on the same site:

> $\ce{H+}$ is born with the help of that plasma in this plus electrode. $\ce{H+}$ is hydrogen with a positive electric charge. Through the air, the $\ce{H+}$ moves to the minus electrode which generates electrons. In here, electron meets $\ce{H+}$ and active hydrogen like me are born.... The electron that is generated in minus electrode in the SPi ion device where [I] am born is naturally combined with oxygen. That is oxygen ion ($\ce{O2-}$). (Active hydrogen and oxygen ion together transform into $\ce{(H-O-O)-}$). $\ce{HOO}$($\ce{HOO-}$) ion envelops the positively charged airborne bio-contaminants and react with three hydrogen constituted of protein components, forming water vapor. This modifies the surface protein or breaks the cell membrane to remove bio-contaminants. $\ce{HOO}$($\ce{HOO-}$) ion reacts only with single cells such as virus or germ but does not react with the human body... $\ce{OH}$ radical is an active oxygen species and one of the highly reactive and strong oxidants. It can be harmful to human's body if exposed for a long time. (Active hydrogen combines with OH radical to form water vapor).

(It has numerous grammatical mistakes which I just copied verbatim).

I would like to know what are the various compounds and radicals mentioned in the explanation, and how the reactions above take place. What is the plasma in the positive electrode, and what is the potential difference between the electrodes that allows the generation of the active hydrogen and oxygen ions? What are the real chemical states of the active hydrogen and the oxygen ions? How do they combine to form the $\ce{HOO-}$ ion? What is the $\ce{HOO-}$ ion and how is it stable enough to go around the room? How does the active hydrogen combine with the $\ce{OH}$ radical?

Comment: Could you elaborate the question a little bit based on what you know about these ions?

Comment: The point is that I don't know *anything* about these ions! And I'm not sure if I'm taking a risk now by copying this from Samsung's website. It's only for educational purposes though.

Comment: I don't think there should be any problem with you copying that, you have cited the website it came from and based on fair use, it should be fine.  I think this will likely help it tremendously to get an answer, tbh, as it's a lot more info for someone to go on.

Answer (score 5):

if you can take a look at the main web site, then it seems they make $\ce{HO2}$ and not $\ce{HO2-}$. This a peroxy radical which exists at trace levels in the ambient atmosphere, usually from reactions of light with oxides of nitrogen and volatile organic compounds. Its really reactive and I don't know for sure how long it will last in the air of the room. It will however react with $\ce{OH}$ radical and make water and $\ce{O2}$. $\ce{HO2 + OH -> O2 + H2O}$. $\ce{HO2}$ will also react with $\ce{NO}$ to form $\ce{NO2}$ and then depending if there is sunlight could make ozone. One of the issues for the machine will be that $\ce{HO2}$ will need to made at some point and therefore one of the first molecules it will encounter will be itself and therefore make $\ce{H2O2}$ (hydrogen peroxide). I think getting one into a lab and testing it would be a start.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE @fumifugium. We have MathJax imbedded into our site to help you format math and chemistry. I have edited your answer to make the formulas look like formulas. Check out our [FAQ](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/faq#what-notation-and-symbols-are-commonly-used-here) to learn how to do this for yourself.

Comment: @BenNorris: Just a note, you can link to the FAQ just by using `[faq]` in a comment (another useful one is `[ask]` for [ask]) See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000) for more. :)

Comment: @Manishearth - thanks for the tip. How do I get that greyed background for the links to show the markup?

Comment: Never mind. `I figured it out.`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the possible inaccuracy of $\ce{(H-O-O)-}$. However, where on the main web site did you look? [This link](http://www.samsung.com/ae/consumer/home-appliances/air-conditioner/air-purifier/SA600CBXSG) also says the same thing.